# Can type inference improve writing code instead of just checking it?

Tags: types, type-conversion, type-inference, inferred-type

Type inference can help with future runtime errors right? Can it help with writing code? For using inference can you find the "least common" or "most common" type of two functions to improve interfacing between them?
Also are there graphs of types for a program in addition to graphs of program topology?

Comment: to the person that voted a close: which site would be a better fit for such a question?

Comment: "Type inference can help with future runtime errors right?" Are you talking about type inference as a language feature or about type inference in static analyses of dynamically typed languages? "can you find the 'least common' or 'most common' type of two functions" Depends on the language and its type system.

Comment: just trying to get a feel for the implications and applications of type inference

Comment: maybe a better question would be: "what's the most amazing way you've used type inference"

Comment: Who's the "you" that question is targeted at? Compiler writers? Language designers? Authors of static analysis tools targeting dynamically typed languages? Programmers in languages with type inference?

Comment: i guess any amazing story would be nice :) although the most useful for a regular programmer might be by Programmers in languages with type inference.

Comment: I feel like we're kinda talking past each other. I'm trying to get a handle on what you're actually asking, but you're not answering in a way that actually clarifies anything. I currently am very lost on what kind of story you're trying to get here. Something like "I once programmed in a language with type inference and I didn't have to write down any type annotations. Amazing!"? That's not really much of a story, but I'm not sure what other kind of story there'd be.

Comment: This is quite an open question. But one example: How can type inference help with code generation. For example if you have two functions which are type incompatible yet you know that they will be a part of the data-flow. To what degree can you generate glue between them?

Comment: "How can type inference help with code generation?" In a statically typed language? It can't. It doesn't matter one bit to the code generation whether the type information it has comes from inference or from type annotations. "To what degree can you generate glue between them?" You mean glue as in automatic type conversions that allow you to pass the result of one function to the other despite having different types? You generally don't want to mix implicit type conversions with type inference.